# Removing unwanted characters from HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, trim

I am not a very professional JavaScript programmer. I want to ask that is it possible to remove all unwanted characters (like *newlines* and also *comments* if possible) from **HTML** page source code using **JavaScript** at runtime whenever page loads? If possible can anyone please suggest me some tutorial?

Comment: How do you define `unwanted characters`?

Comment: What would be the point of that? The only benefit to removing those things is that less bandwidth is needed to deliver the page to the client. If you remove them *after* the page has been delivered, then the benefit is lost. (Or were you talking about server side JS such as in node.js or Classic ASP?)

Answer (score 1):

Is this is what you need...?

```
   <script language="JavaScript">
      var temp = new String('This is a te!!!!st st>ring... from ??which? you.. want to remove chars...');
      document.write(temp + '<br>');
      temp =  temp.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
      document.write(temp + '<br>');
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do that using a JS but if you are running an server or an VPS and is linux based, you can use mod_pagespeed

http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/

Here are some of the features:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/config_filters